# Rails issue with iterating over a hash for the View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, jruby

I have this hash. I am trying to render in a view. Which me being so new to Rails I haven't the slightest clue how to do it. What I need to do over all is be able to sort things by either service_name or by host and build blocks according to that. I've tried a dozen or so things but I can't seem to work with this properly so I need any help I can get at this point.

An example of what I am trying to do:

[image: example]

Below is the hash. Best I've gotten so far is just the Service name to list independently without sorting or anything else.

```
services_hash = {
    :status => "successful",
    :service_list => [
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "oozie",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-namenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "single-database",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "datanode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "secondarynamenode",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "web",
            :status => "DEAD",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "tasktracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Service",
            :host => "1"
        },
        {
            :service_name => "jobtracker",
            :status => "RUNNING",
            :status_message => "Running Master Service",
            :host => "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

**edit**
Below is 2 things one I tried, one someone else helped me come to the conclusion of for the sorting. Both work to a point. But when I went to combine the ideas I failed miserably. I have since scrapped my combination effort coming here to hope to find an answer how to do it so I can iterate over the hash to reproduce the above image to some effect or another.

Note currently I realize the output of the HTML would not completely resemble the image. Right now I am am stuck with the if-else portion of it, as the way I am trying it seems to skip over it.

- 

```
<%
val = @service_hash
svcs = val[:service_list]
puts "#{svcs.size} service entries."

grouped = svcs.group_by { |svc| svc[:service_name] }
puts "#{grouped.size} named services:"

grouped.keys.sort.each do |name|
    puts "  service: #{name}"
    grouped[name].each do |svc|
        puts "     host: #{svc[:host]}"
        puts "   status: #{svc[:status]}"
        puts "           #{svc[:status_message]}"
    end
    puts '-'*40
end
%>
```

Comment: What was wrong with what I provided yesterday?

Comment: its only spitting into the console, then I broke it trying to actually get it to resemble the above image im trying to recreate

Comment: So what's the actual issue? The mechanism for sorting/etc. has been provided. You can't create the HTML?

Comment: seems as I can't provide the HTML. Well rather have the Server side stuff render it like I'd like to render it. Rails is nice, but its making me feel like when I first picked up programming 13 years ago, just cant seem to get nothing to work for me the way I want with it.

Comment: Im more of a PHP & JavaScript guy myself. But the project Im working on with someone is Rails, I am doing most of the JavaScript stuff, but I need the UI to render accordingly so I can manipulate it the way its desired in the end run with JavaScript

Comment: What do you mean, you can't provide the HTML? Not sure what you mean by "rather have the server side stuff render it like I'd like to render it".

Comment: well seeing as the hash is made dynamicly on the back end in a controller then spit to the front end view. Theres no way of telling how long that view will be, or if it will have all the services, or hosts I would be looking for either way. And for some reason when ever I try to take whats given and run over it to build out the containers 8 in this example or 1 pending on which way I want to list them and have them build a UL/LI combination per to signify a block I cant get it to do it. I dont know what I did wrong. But Im in a crunch and at a loss currently for what ive done wrong

Comment: You know templates are rendered on the server, right? The contents of the hash are not relevant. Since you know PHP, write it in PHP first, then translate it to Ruby.

Comment: basically I am looking to in a gritty way itterate over it once its sorted based on the sort choice. Then if-else through it to make it show containers based on sort type. The way you showed me the other day works nicely as far as it showing up in a log like enviroment or in the console window through linux. But I need to go over it so I can rebuild the concept image above. PHP I would have already nailed it down no question, In javascript I had it nailed down to, but the guys Im helping out want it all in the view prior to dom manipulation

Comment: So write it in PHP and translate it to Ruby. What you do with the iteration doesn't have a lot to do with Ruby, it has to do with inserting HTML tags in the appropriate locations. You're not describing the actual *issue* you're having very well.

Comment: edited OP, but I still don't know if thats going to translate well to what I am trying to convey. Right now at this point I need something to work. Im sorry Im not good with verbalizing my issue. This is probably why I am frustrated with it all.

Comment: That's just the original code inside `<% %>` tags; what ERb have you tried so far? What's wrong with building this out in PHP then translating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby on Rails `puts` doesn't write to the output buffer.  In an ERB the return value of a code block inside `<%=  %>` will be written to the output.  So in your view your code should look more like this:

```
# ERB View Template
<%
  val = @service_hash
  svcs = val[:service_list] # This should probably be done in a controller rather than a view.
%>

<%= svcs.size %> service entries.

<%
  grouped = svcs.group_by { |svc| svc[:service_name] } # Again, this should probably be in a controller
%>

<%= grouped.size %> named services:

<% grouped.keys.sort.each do |name| %>
  service: <%= name %>
  <% grouped[name].each do |svc| %>
    host: <%= svc[:host] %>
    status: <% svc[:status] %>
    <%= svc[:status_message] %>
  <% end %>
  <%= '-'*40 %>

<% end %>
```